# WKInterfaceDevice caching optimization

Tags: watchkit

I am trying to cache rendered animations to the apple watch (these are generated at run time). I have saved the frames of each animation as JPEG @1x with compression of 0.1. The sum of all the frames is less then 1.2 MB. I clear the cache before I start caching. However only about half the animations are cached. The documentation says that the cache is 5MB. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you caching the frames? If you're using the `WKInterfaceDevice` method `addCachedImage:name:`, you'll be using up a lot of of the cache. If you're already using `addCachedImageWithData:name:` to send the JPEG-encoded `NSData`, then it's likely something else.

Comment: I am using `addCachedImage:name:`, because the images I am sending are animated. I am not sure how to turn animated images into data. I tried using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` however that just serialized the first image.

Comment: OpenRadar http://openradar.appspot.com/20839855

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send image data to the Watch programmatically (i.e. not at compile time), `WKInterfaceDevice` provides two methods:

1. `addCachedImage:name:` accepts a `UIImage`, encodes it as PNG image data, and transmits it to the cache. So, if you create a `UIImage` from JPEG data, you are actually decoding the JPEG data into an image, then re-encoding it as PNG before it's sent to the cache (thereby negating the effects of JPEG-encoding in the first place).
2. `addCachedImageWithData:name:` accepts `NSData` and transmits the unaltered data directly to the cache. So, if you encode your image to `NSData` using `UIImageJpegRepresentation` and pass it to this method, you'll transmit and store less in the cache. I use this technique for all of my images, unless I need the benefits of a PNG image; in that case, I actually encode my own `NSData` using `UIImagePngRepresentation` and send it using this method.

For debugging purposes, it's helpful to use the `[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] cachedImages]` dictionary to find the size of the cached image data. The dictionary returns a `NSNumber` with the size (in bytes) of the cache entry.

Comment: I am unable to send animated images using addCachedImageWithData:name:. If I convert the animated image to jpeg data and then reload the image using imageWithData: the resulting image is not animated. The documentation indicates that this api can accept animated images. So there should be a way

Comment: Correct. The problem is when you send them as UIImages, they're full-sized (in memory) images, regardless of how you originally encoded them. You'll either have to lower the number of frames/resolution of your animated UIImage (to reduce the memory footprint) or send the frames as individually-numbered images, then use `WKInterfaceImage`'s `startAnimating` method.

Comment: I have tried to send each image individually named "imageN" where N is their index. Then tried to load the image using `[wkimage setImageNamed:@"image"];` . To start animating I used `[wkimage startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, N) duration:0.4 repeatCount:1];`. This did not work. The `setImageNamed` call returned that no image existed with that name.

Comment: Here is a gist that shows the code I am using to test this solution. https://gist.github.com/datinc/3c671cbc2a04fd395122

Comment: For what it's worth, that didn't work for me either. It appears that you can't send individually numbered frames to the cache and animate them like bundle images. That's news to me, and I wonder if it's a bug. It sounds like the two approaches that will work for you are: 1) include them in the assets library of your Watch app, or 2) reduce the size/frames of your animation to fit under 5MB.

Comment: By the way, when you send a UIImage directly, you can roughly figure the total bytes as: height x width x 4 x frameCount.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that if you use this line of code:

```
[self.image setImageNamed:@"number"]
```

Your images should be named:

```
number1.png
number2.png
number3.png
number4.png
```

I was running into a similar error when I had my images named:

```
number001.png
number002.png
number003.png
number004.png
```